How to track affiliates sales on wordpress without woocommerce/products/carts?
Wordpress website and it sells a service, the payment collected by 3rd party payment provider link. This payment provider has no integration to cart/woocommerce/wordpress so the traditional affiliate manager plugins will not be able to track the sales since the service is also not listed on wordpress as a product. But has a landing page and button with linked payment link.
So how will it be possible to generate an affiliate link for free and provide to affiliates where they can then promote it and when clients click that payment button and go to next link and complete payment we get back data that client has gone to payment checkout of 3rd party payment provider and through affilate called mr/ms abc. And what way would be there to also showcase this data to the affiliate as well so they can check themselves?
The 3rd party payment provider when click their payment link goes to an initial page asking for billing details and then when click next asks to select payment card type and then next page enter card details and payment completed.
Any ideas solutions for this?

@moshesimantov can you help answer?

@moshe-simantov can you help answer?
